# "Error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty" persists after fixing

Tags: android, xml

I decided to upgrade Android Studio today against my own better judgment. After upgrading, building the project failed due to

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  /home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/project/mobile/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:841: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
```

Line 841 was an `<item>`.

So I removed all the `<item>` bodies in `values.xml` like so:

```
<item name="item_1" type="id">Item 1</item>
```

to

```
<item name="item_1" type="id"/>
```

This did not fix the problem, as the same error is being thrown. The traceback now refers to a `<string>` resource in my `values.xml` file. There are no `<item>`s in the file that aren't fixed, so now I'm stuck. I've also tried the usual `invalidate caches & restart`, `sync with Gradle files`, `clean` and `build` stuff to no avail.

**Edit**:

I quickly noticed that upon building the project, line 841 (from the first traceback) is dynamically changed to the old `<item>` style, thus throwing the Exception. The source code XML file is free of the bodies, but the build-generated XML file generates it with a body in the item elements.

Removing the body from these tags does nothing, as the body is re-added on runtime every single time.

Comment: If it's referring to a `<string>` element, you should be looking at your `<string>` elements rather than `<item>`.

Comment: @TheWanderer the traceback specifically says `error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.`. If the `<string>` elements are to blame for this, I'm really lost on how to troubleshoot!

Comment: So the error says `<item>` but clicks through to a `<string>`? Can you pastebin your XML?

Comment: @TheWanderer exactly! see my edits please.

Comment: Make sure you're editing the right file; i.e., the source file, not a build-generated file.

Comment: @MikeM. the source file is free of this issue: it's the build-gen file that keeps throwing the exception.

Comment: Did you try cleaning/rebuilding the project?

Comment: @MikeM. yes, `Clean Project` throws the exception, however.

Comment: Well, sounds like you might have more than one line with an error.